# How many sets of four consecutive positive integers are there such that the product of the four integers is less than $100,000$?

Tags: combinatorics

I know how to get the solution by experimentation. $(16, 17, 18, 19) = 93,024$
is the largest set which produces a product that is less than $100,000$, thus, there are 16 sets of four consecutive positive integers that meet the criteria.

What I'm interested in knowing is if there is a neater solution to this problem that does not involve much calculation. Can we use estimation or some nice properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AM GM inequality yields

$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\le(n+1.5)^4$$

So, if
$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)>10^k$$
then
$$n>10^{k/4}-1.5$$

Therefore, a good first approximation for the first of the four numbers can be
$$\lfloor 10^{k/4}-1.5\rfloor$$

Comment: @AdamHughes and ajotatxe,That's not AM-GM, It will result in :$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\le(n+1.5)^4$$

Comment: @JaideepKhare ah, good catch! A shame too, that would have given a nice way to get all the way down to $16$ as an upper-bound!

Comment: @ajotatxe, and I have reversed my vote too. +1

Answer (score 5):

Low-balling says if the product is $P$ and the first number is $n$ then $n^4< P$. So consider $\sqrt[4]{100000}\approx 17.78$ and we see $17^4< 100000$ is the last possible $n$, so testing $n=17$ fails, but pushing it down to $16$ works and you're done.

Comment: Why estimate using a 4th power ? Is it because we have 4 numbers ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=P$, if I replace all the $(n+k)$ with $n$ it gives $n^4$.